# Generating data on server-side and sending it to client?

Tags: python, html

How would you write a webpage that would request (execution of) a python script on the server and then take output from that script and send it back to the browser?

I'm currently taking a web programming course and have probably spent more time looking up documentation and asking questions than writing code! Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, but most of them involve the Web Server Gateway Interface [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface). Look for a web server (Apache, Cherokee, etc) that supports WSGI and use something like this `Hello World`

```
def application(environ, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
  yield 'Hello World\n'
```